# Sum number values associated with letter values

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I have a system of scoring that uses letters paired with numerical values.

| letters | values |
| --- | --- |
| A | 26 |
| B | 25 |
| C | 24 |
| D | 23 |
| E | 22 |
| F | 21 |

In my data, I have columns that are populated with `letters` and for the `letters` in each row I want to SUM their associated `values`.

| Cat.1 | Cat.2 | Cat.3 | Cat.4 | SUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | F | F | B | 93 |
| B | E | A | A | 99 |
| C | D | D | E | 92 |

In the table above the first SUM returns `93` because `SUM(A,F,F,B)` is equivalent to `SUM(26,21,21,25)=93`

I have tried to find an answer online, but I'm having a hard time finding one that is specific to my problem.

Please note that I have very basic knowledge of Google Sheets/Excel, so I would like to keep it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

## Formula

```
=SUM(
   ARRAYFORMULA(
     91-CODE(range_of_letters)))
```

## Explanation

This formula leverages the [CODE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094122?hl=en) function to convert the capital letters to their associated values.

1. The [CODE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094122?hl=en) function returns a value for each capital letter:

   ```
   CODE("A")= 65
   CODE("B")= 66
   CODE("C")= 67   // and so on
   ```
2. That value is then subtracted from `65` (the value for `A`) so that the each letter is now equivalent to

   ```
   65-CODE("A")=  0
   65-CODE("B")= -1
   65-CODE("C")= -2  // and so on
   ```
3. Then `26` is added to each value so the letters are now equivalent to

   ```
   91-CODE("A")= 26
   91-CODE("B")= 25
   91-CODE("C")= 24  // and so on
   ```
4. The calculation is placed in an [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) function so that a range of letters can be converted at once, and the resulting array is passed to a [SUM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669?hl=en) function:

   ```
   =SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(91-CODE("A","B","C"))) 
   =SUM({91-65, 91-66, 91-67})
   =SUM({26, 25, 24})
   =75
   ```